# Understanding the structure of $SO(3)$ as a manifold

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I know that $SO(3)$ is a matrix Lie group and therefore a smooth manifold. It has dimension three and I know that it can be, as a manifold constructed by identifying the antipodal points of $\mathbb S^3$.

I also know the ["plate trick"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_trick), that gives a hint that $SO(3)$ is not simply connected. In particular, we cannot take a closed path and shrink it down to a single point. But the plate trick shows us that we can shrink a closed path that goes around twice down to a single point.

I cannot wrap my head around how to imagine the structure of $SO(3)$ as a manifold. Is there maybe a nice projection into the $\mathbb R^4$ or even $\mathbb R^3$, where we can easily see that a closed path that goes around twice can be shrunken down to a single point?

Comment: Note that $SO(3)\cong \Bbb R\rm{P}^3$ as manifolds: I'm not sure there are simple visualizations of projective spaces.

Comment: To see that the fundamental group of ${\rm SO}(3)$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, take the 2-sheeted covering $\mathbb S^3\rightarrow {\rm SO}(3)$. Take a closed loop in ${\rm SO}(3)$ and lift it to a path in $\mathbb S^3$, which will either be a closed loop or a path connecting two antipodal points. But then lifting the same loop to a path starting from the antipodal point, it has to end at the starting point of the previous lift; hence twice our closed loop in ${\rm SO}(3)$ lifts in any case to a closed loop in $\mathbb S^3$, which of course is simply connected.